# How to get the latency from the ping command in java

Tags: java

with this code I get the latency from the server, but I am not able to safe it in a variable.

I already tried it, but unfortunatly I am kind of new in java and can't solve this problem.
How can I get the average latency in a variable in milliseconds (ms)?

Thanks for the help!

Edit: I need the average latency, so I just need the value of "Mittelwert" - in this example the value "25" in a variable.
So I added the code from J.Doe to my code and changed "time" to "Mittelwert" and changed

> "String timeWithValue = s.split(" = ")[2];"
>
> > "String value = timeWithValue.split("ms")[0]"

So this code need to get inserted in the code, then the average latency in form of "Mittelwert" will get safed in the variable "latency".

But now the output don't return "average latency: 25". The average latency don't get returned at all. Someone know why this happens?

```
 System.out.println("here is the average latency :\n");
double latency = 0.0;
while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null)
{
    if (s.contains("Mittelwert")) {
        String timeWithValue = s.split(" = ")[2];
        String value = timeWithValue.split("ms")[0];
        latency = Double.parseDouble(value);
        System.out.println("latency " + latency);
    }
}

Output: 
Here is the standard output of the command:


Ping wird ausgef?hrt f?r 74.125.236.73 [2a00:1f78:fffd:9::d435:9868] mit 32 Bytes Daten:
Antwort von 2a00:1f78:fffd:9::d435:9868: Zeit=26ms 
Antwort von 2a00:1f78:fffd:9::d435:9868: Zeit=25ms 
Antwort von 2a00:1f78:fffd:9::d435:9868: Zeit=25ms 
Antwort von 2a00:1f78:fffd:9::d435:9868: Zeit=29ms 

Ping-Statistik f?r 2a00:1f78:fffd:9::d435:9868:
    Pakete: Gesendet = 4, Empfangen = 4, Verloren = 0
    (0% Verlust),
Ca. Zeitangaben in Millisek.:
    Minimum = 25ms, Maximum = 29ms, Mittelwert = 26ms
Here is the standard error of the command (if any):

here is the average latency :










import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class JavaPingExampleProgram
{

  public static void main(String args[]) 
  throws IOException
  {
    // create the ping command as a list of strings
    JavaPingExampleProgram ping = new JavaPingExampleProgram();
    List<String> commands = new ArrayList<String>();
    commands.add("ping");
    //commands.add("-c");
    //commands.add("5");
    commands.add("74.125.236.73");
    ping.doCommand(commands);
  }

  public void doCommand(List<String> command) 
  throws IOException
  {
    String s = null;

    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
    Process process = pb.start();

    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
    
    // read the output from the command
    System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
    while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null)
    {
      System.out.println(s);
    }

    // read any errors from the attempted command
    System.out.println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
    while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null)
    {
      System.out.println(s);
    }
  }

}



Output:
Here is the standard output of the command:


Ping wird ausgef?hrt f?r 74.125.236.73 [2a00:1f78:fffd:9::d435:9868] mit 32 Bytes Daten:
Antwort von 2a00:1f78:fffd:9::d435:9868: Zeit=26ms 
Antwort von 2a00:1f78:fffd:9::d435:9868: Zeit=25ms 
Antwort von 2a00:1f78:fffd:9::d435:9868: Zeit=24ms 
Antwort von 2a00:1f78:fffd:9::d435:9868: Zeit=25ms 

Ping-Statistik f?r 2a00:1f78:fffd:9::d435:9868:
    Pakete: Gesendet = 4, Empfangen = 4, Verloren = 0
    (0% Verlust),
Ca. Zeitangaben in Millisek.:
    Minimum = 24ms, Maximum = 26ms, Mittelwert = 25ms
Here is the standard error of the command (if any):
```

Comment: Do you know where the `String`s containing the latency are being passed around?

Comment: You have the text data coming in via your stdInput.readLine() call.  Instead of printing that, you could apply a regular expression to it to extract out the latency value, and then you could convert that string to a floating point vaule. - Can you show us the output you're getting? (put it in the question, not as a comment, please)

Answer (score 2):

if your output is like

```
PING google.de (216.58.208.35): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 216.58.208.35: icmp_seq=0 ttl=118 time=22.126 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.208.35: icmp_seq=1 ttl=118 time=27.877 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.208.35: icmp_seq=2 ttl=118 time=18.077 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.208.35: icmp_seq=3 ttl=118 time=33.099 ms
```

try this:

```
while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null)
        {
            if (s.contains("time")) {
                String timeWithValue = s.split(" ")[6];
                String value = timeWithValue.split("=")[1];
                double latency = Double.parseDouble(value);
                System.out.println(latency);
            }

        }
```

Comment: I guess, you have to change the array index of the first split from 6 to 3. Which one did you try?

Comment: Ah, and I see,  you will also have to extract the number from the unit after the second split: 24ms

Comment: I guess, you're getting the IndexOutOfBounds because your later input also contains _Zeit_ `Ca. Zeitangaben`